# Field validation in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I put a captcha on the password recovery page : `wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`

When I enter a wrong email in the email field and then click on the recover button, it says that :

> **Error:** There is no account with that username or
> email address.

If you have to click on the restore button, it says please fill in the captcha field, and after filling the captcha field correctly and clicking on the restore button, it will show the message that there is no account.

I found the hook : `lostpassword_user_data`

How should I insist that you fill in the captcha field first and then notify that this email does not exist?